# How to hide main HTML overflow when another overflow is displayed?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm working on my first website where i will sell music production. When I open the playlist (it is opened in full size) the main overflow is displayed with the overflow of the playlist and that don't look nice to me.

When the playlist is displayed :

```
<div class="playlist-wrapper" id="playlist-wrapper" style="display: block;">
// Playlist content
</div>
```

When the playlist is not displayed :

```
<div class="playlist-wrapper" id="playlist-wrapper">
// Playlist content
</div>
```

[Double Overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APuZJ.jpg)

Comment: How do you open and close the list? by clicking on a link? You have to attach a javascript event listener to that event. Please say how do you toggle the list so I can help.

Comment: This appears to be a styling issue. Maybe you could post your CSS, or better yet create a working [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You basically have a couple of elements which have `overflow-y:scroll` which is causing this. You need to find these elements and make sure that it is only applied to one element. Below are examples of what you currently have and what you need to have. Hope it helps!

Currently have:

```css
.wrapper{
  height:400px;
}
.inner-wrapper{
  height:600px;
}
.inner-inner-wrapper{
  height:800px;
}

/* Apply overflow-y to all the divs*/
div{
  width:100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <div class="inner-inner-wrapper">
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What you need to have:

```css
.wrapper{
  height:400px;
}
.inner-wrapper{
  height:600px;
}
.inner-inner-wrapper{
  height:800px;
}
.wrapper{
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
div{
  width:100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <div class="inner-inner-wrapper">
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my button

```
<button id="playlist-toggle" class="jplayerButton">
//Button
</button>
```

I want to hide the main overflow on  when i click on this button the first time so when open the playlist and show the main overflow again when i close the playlist